# Cmake: how to force including more than one header

Tags: visual-studio, header, cmake

I try to force including header with CMake(2.8.2) and this first solution:

```
   SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${MyTarget} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/FI\"${ForcedHeader_A}\"/FI\"${ForcedHeader_B}\"")
```

Somehow CMake ignores (or overwrites) the first compiler flag. This happens only if the two compiler flags are the same as in this case . I have to port something I dont want to modify the software structure at this moment. Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this (note also that recent CMake means you don't need to USE_CAPS_ALL_THE_TIME):

```
get_target_property(FLAGS ${MyTarget} COMPILE_FLAGS)
set_target_properties(${MyTarget} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${FLAGS} /FI\"${ForcedHeader_A}\"/FI\"${ForcedHeader_B}\"")
```

Comment: Thanks  Jack, but it should work this way.  get_target_property(FLAGS ${MyTarget} COMPILE_FLAGS) set_target_properties(${MyTarget} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${FLAGS} /FI\"${ForcedHeader_A}\"/FI\"${ForcedHeader_B}\"")

Comment: Sorry, it was just sent.
 set (FLAG "${FLAGS}    "/FI\"${ForcedHeader_A}\""     "\"${ForcedHeader_A}\"")
 set_target_properties(${MyTarget} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${FLAGS}") 

 # Please note that the second flag must not  have the option /FI in front,  this is an internal problem of the CMake Parser I guess.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand that. If you've worked it out, you should answer your own question (there's nothing wrong with answering your own questions) and then accept the answer.